# How to delete a dictionary list items

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
inventory = {'gold' : 500, 
        'pouch' : ['flint', 'twine', 'gemstone'], 
        'backpack' : ['xylophone','dagger', 'bedroll','bread loaf']}
```

How can I remove the dagger from it ?

I tried this:

```
inventory["backpack"][1].remove()
```

or

```
del inventory["backpack"][1]
```

but It made this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 15, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: ```del inventory["backpack"][1]``` works fine for me.

Comment: This made me this error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 15, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item deletion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inventory["backpack"][1].remove() - applied remove on inventory["backpack"][1] which is a string and has no remove attribute.

You can also use slice to delete it-

```
inventory["backpack"] = inventory["backpack"][:1] + inventory["backpack"][2:]
```

or -

```
inventory["backpack"].remove(inventory["backpack"][1])
```

Same follows for - del inventory["backpack"][1]. You apply del on list object but it does not have such an attirbute.

Comment: Obvious to me is `inventory['backpack'].remove('dagger')`